# IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to Activity when finish AsyncTask & Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am using `ProgressDialog` in `AsyncTask`. And If user Press Back Button, then `AsyncTask` will be cancelled, current fragment will replace by any other `Fragment`.
There is no issue if user is still on Application. Bu if he goes back and back speedly and at last stop application, It gives error `IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to Activity`.
How to solve this ?
**My Code:**

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Loading...", true,
                    true, new OnCancelListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            CancelDialog();
                        }
                    });
        }
public void CancelDialog() {

        new FetchData().cancel(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }

        ((FrameLayout) flMain).removeAllViews();

        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, new Home()).commit();
    }
```

**Home.java:**

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                    getView().clearFocus();
                    getActivity().finish();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After so many tried, lastly I have found Simple Answer: [isAdded()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded%28%29)

It will Return true if the `Fragment` is currently added to its `Activity`.

I used below code and it solved my problem.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    if(isAdded()){
        // Code to display Data...
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know I uses yet allways `if(getActivity() != null)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful when to call e.g getActivity() - your fragment might not (yet/already) be attached to an activity when you call such methods. Check out [this.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

Alternatively you can save the Activity instance when [onAttach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)) is called, but then you'll have to be careful what you do with that Activity instance, so that you do not make conflicting updates with another Fragment that is actually still attached.

[isAdded](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) and [isDetached](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isDetached()) can be useful to check the state and avoid calling invalid methods.

Comment: I have called `onResume()` on Home(), and that AsyncTask is in another Fragment.

Comment: You are calling `getActivity()` in both code snippets, so that could be a problem if those are Fragments, and they get detached before `getActivity()` is called.